# I want to open Google maps app with turn by turn directions with voice navigation in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps

I want to open default google maps app with turn bu turn directions with voice navigation. 
I have used the following code to open google maps app with source location and destination location. Google maps app opened fine and turn by turn directions are also working, but voice navigation is not working.
Please help me on this.

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"googlemaps://maps.google.com/maps?output=embed&saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",[@"30.886537" doubleValue], [@"75.838870" doubleValue],[@"30.711423" doubleValue],[@"76.690839" doubleValue]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following function:

```
location = "(self.street!) (self.zip!) (self.city!) (self.country!)"
func showLocationPoints(location:String)
{

    let geocoder:CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if((error) != nil){
            print("Error", error)
        }
        else if let placemark = placemarks!.first
        {
            let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
            let pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            pointAnnotation.coordinate = coordinates
            pointAnnotation.title = "Apple HQ"

            let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01 , 0.01)
            let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinates, span)
            self.mapView?.setRegion(region, animated: true)

            self.mapView?.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)
            self.mapView?.centerCoordinate = coordinates
            self.mapView?.selectAnnotation(pointAnnotation, animated: true)
            print("Added annotation to map view")

            let place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
            let mapItem = MKMapItem (placemark: place)

            mapItem.name = location

            let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: true]
            MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([mapItem], launchOptions: options as? [String : AnyObject])

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: He is asking about Google Maps, not Apple Maps.